# Keyboard character used is undefined

Tags: characters, input-encodings

My reference list include letters from different languages, such as `á, ö, 第`.

I get

> ! Package inputenc Error: Keyboard character used is
>   undefined

## EDIT

[Copied from deleted answer by cfr as the OP cannot currently access the account.]

Augustin's suggestion solved part of the problem. It still do not want to work with `第` (and the likes).

> ! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:第 not set up for use with
>   LaTeX.

I did try to, as per one of the answers, create a new document and try again. It did not work.

Comment: This should help: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/193679/%C3%A6-%C3%B8-%C3%A5-giving-package-inputenc-error-keyboard-character-used-is-undefined Most likely you have problems with the character encoding of your file (I recommend going for utf8).

Comment: You would need to declare the unicode character. However, without seeing a complete example, it is hard to be of much help. Are you sure that you can *output* this? Even if you declare the character for *input*, it will only get typeset if it corresponds to something available.

Comment: You can have accounts merged by following the instructions at http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts

Comment: Cheers for the comments. Merged the accounts and managed to build the document. I didn't solve the issue, edited the reference that caused the issue (removed the unknown characters).

Would still be nice to know how the get around it, though. Might need it a rainy day.

The problem was with a reference I wanted to include an alternative title for.

`\bibitem{key-12} something 京都议定书, 1997.`